# DataBind a ListArray data type to a Candlestick Chart series

Tags: c#, data-binding, charts

Having trouble binding a ListArray to a candlestick chart in C# (VS2015). I've been banging my head on my desk for a day now... so time to ask. :) It appears to me the chart class really wants to be tied to a database.  I'd like to be able to generate small amounts of equity data and then push it into a candlestick chart.
my code:

```
public class Record
{
    int id;
    string time_stamp;
    double open, close, high, low;
    public Record(int id, string time_stamp, double open, double close, double high, double low)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.open = open;
        this.close = close;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string TimeStamp
    {
        get { return time_stamp; }
        set { time_stamp = value; }
    }
    public double Open
    {
        get { return open; }
        set { open = value; }
    }
    public double Close
    {
        get { return close; }
        set { close = value; }
    }
    public double High
    {
        get { return high; }
        set { high = value; }
    }
    public double Low
    {
        get { return low; }
        set { low = value; }
    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ArrayList listDataSource = new ArrayList();

        //add some members to list
        listDataSource.Add(new Record(1, "4 oclock", 10, 5, 7, 8));
        listDataSource.Add(new Record(1, "5 oclock", 11, 4, 4, 9));

        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Time";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "High, Low, Open, Close";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].CustomProperties = "PrieceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=green";
        chart1.Series["Series1"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
        chart1.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;
        chart1.DataSource = listDataSource;
        chart1.DataBind(); // fails to bind
    }
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you are referencing `Time` which doesn't exist and you should be referencing `TimeStamp`. You also need to set the value of `TimeStamp` in your constructor.

**Update:** This is what it looks like with the working code below:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ArrayList listDataSource = new ArrayList();

        //add some members to list
        listDataSource.Add(new Record(1, "4 oclock", 10, 5, 7, 8));
        listDataSource.Add(new Record(1, "5 oclock", 11, 4, 4, 9));



        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "TimeStamp";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "High, Low, Open, Close";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].CustomProperties = "PrieceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=green";
        chart1.Series["Series1"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
        chart1.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;

        chart1.DataSource = listDataSource;

        chart1.DataBind();

    }

}

public class Record
{
    int id;
    string time_stamp;
    double open, close, high, low;
    public Record(int id, string time_stamp, double open, double close, double high, double low)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.time_stamp = time_stamp;
        this.open = open;
        this.close = close;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string TimeStamp
    {
        get { return time_stamp; }
        set { time_stamp = value; }
    }
    public double Open
    {
        get { return open; }
        set { open = value; }
    }
    public double Close
    {
        get { return close; }
        set { close = value; }
    }
    public double High
    {
        get { return high; }
        set { high = value; }
    }
    public double Low
    {
        get { return low; }
        set { low = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch there.  It now runs.  However series1 is not displayed on the chart.

Comment: @Chipcraft I have updated with a screenshot and the working code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Adam!  That is perfect.  I'm finding the documentation on these visual studio fairly lacking.

Comment: @Chipcraft agreed.